# Scalable AllegroGraph on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, allegrograph

I'm thinking of using AllegroGraph, but there's an issue! Can it be used on Azure? Did anyone already did it? I've got a Linux machine in which I'm thinking of installing AllegroGraph Server. There's already a MongoDB instance there, the idea is to connect them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using a Linux VM, I don't what Windows Azure has to do with whether this will work or not. If it runs on whatever Linux distro you're using, it should work.

Comment: I have no knowledge of AllegroGraph, so I have no idea if/how it scales.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it and it works like a charm, simple installation.
Just remind of opening the doors needed to either access the webview or other software like Gruff.